# C++: Differences between using Structs or Enums for overloading constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, enums, overloading

I can use either a struct or an enum to overload constructors, and they both seem to do the same job. in fact, changing from one to the other doesn't even show any differences when diff'ing the two executables using each. But, which is proper?

This:

```
enum PointLocalCoord{ local };
enum PointGlobalCoord{ global };

class Point {
    Point( const PointLocalCoord, const int x, const int y )
        {  /* something */  }
    Point( const PointGlobalCoord, const int x, const int y )
        {  /* something else */  }
};
```

or This:

```
struct local{};
struct global{};

class Point {
    Point( const local, const int x, const int y )
        {  /* something */  }
    Point( const global, const int x, const int y )
        {  /* something else */  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is good. You should have strongly semantic types, even for quantities of the same dimension, and *conversion functions* between them:

```
struct LocalPoint { int x; int y; };
struct GlobalPoint { int x; int y; };

LocalPoint getLocal(GlobalPoint const & gp) { /* remainder? */ }
GlobalPoint getGlobal(LocalPoint const & lp, int offset_x, int offset_y);
```

Now you can make constructors for each point type directly.

The upshot here is that a semantic point class is much better than two random, meaningless integers.

Comment: in this example, you're probably right. however there are cases where I can't see how this would be work, like for avoiding construction of a base class from a derived class.
like so: enum SkipConstructor{ skip_ctor }; and then a derived ctor like this: Derived():Base( skip_ctor ){}

Comment: @zeroth: I don't understand why you'd want to "avoid construction of the base class from a derived class". On the face of it that looks like some serious design abuse. Perhaps you could post a more representative example of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The only reason I've had to skip construction of a base class is in my Matrix classes. I have Mat3x3f and Mat4x4f in an OpenGL app. I'll never need any matrices of other dimensions, and anything a Mat3x3 does, Mat4x4 does the exact same way. so Mat4x4 inherits all Mat3x3's methods. However, that means the base class's array (it's only data members, on the heap) needs to point to the same data as the derived's, only one set of data for either. Either I allow the base class to allocate memory and then immediately delete it in the derived class, or I skip the allocation in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Both work in the sense that they compile, but you should choose one based on logic. In your case, I'm thinking it should be an `enum`, but slightly different:

```
enum PointCoordType
{
    local,
    global
};
class Point {
    Point( PointCoordType, const int x, const int y )
        {  /* something */  }
};
```

Or even having two types of `Point` classes:

```
LocalPoint : Point
```

and

```
GlobalPoint : Point
```

Comment: In this situation, you'd do something different with x and y in the same constructor. You'd be steering away from the "one function should do one thing" philosophy, unless you split them into other methods that the constructor calls. but at this point, you might as well just have two constructors as opposed to one constructor plus two more methods functions.